# Angular - How to detect a 'path' change without getting triggered with every queryParam change?

Tags: angular

I would like to have a subscription for my "path" changes. I have a routing module, which defines multiple paths.

**This kind of subscription is called unfortunately too often, with every query param change within the same path/route**:

```
constructor(router:Router) {
  router.events
    .filter(event => event instanceof NavigationStart)
    .subscribe((event:NavigationStart) => {
      // You only receive NavigationStart events
    });
}
```

I really want to be informed on only path changes. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1):

This can be handled by using the `rxjs` operator `distinctUnitlUnchanged` this will trigger the event only when the condition is true, here we can strip the queryParams and compare the urls and remove the unnecessary events!

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  Router,
  Event,
  NavigationStart,
  NavigationEnd,
  NavigationError,
} from '@angular/router';
import { distinctUntilChanged, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.sass'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'detect-route-change';
  currentRoute: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) {
    this.currentRoute = '';
    this.router.events
      .pipe(
        filter((event) => event instanceof NavigationStart),
        distinctUntilChanged((x: NavigationStart, y: NavigationStart) => {
          const left =
            x && x.url && x.url.includes('?') ? x.url.split('?')[0] : x.url;
          const right =
            y && y.url && y.url.includes('?') ? y.url.split('?')[0] : y.url;
          return left === right;
        })
      )
      .subscribe((event: Event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
          // Show loading indicator
          console.log('Route change detected');
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          // Hide loading indicator
          this.currentRoute = event.url;
          console.log(event);
        }

        if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
          // Hide loading indicator

          // Present error to user
          console.log(event.error);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-detect-route-change-q2yfo8)

Comment: strange, that angular does not provide sth. like this out of the box.. one of the most simple needs.. on which path am I?

Comment: @akcasoy I don't understand the question, does this solve your issue?

Comment: I just questioned it why it is damn so hard to get notified in this case... it is a very common need in nearly every app with routing. But i would still prefer a solution, in which the pipe is not called at all. In this case, the logic in distinctUntilChanged is still called everytime, with every query-parameter change.

Comment: @akcasoy each language/framework has it quirks, just have to live with it :) please close the ticket if your issue is resolved!

Comment: @akcasoy from what I understood, I don't see it's a common scenario. It would be great if you can share a reference where other framework/library solving this problem relatively simple way? Looking forward to learn

Comment: Nice. This should work by handling Url check excluding `queryParams`